# Order of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=\sum c_nz^n$ is an entire function of finite order then show that
$$\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \dfrac{-\log|c_n|}{n\log n}$$
is positive i.e. $\alpha>0$.

I know that if $\lambda$ is the order of an entire function $f(z)=\sum c_nz^n$ then $$\lambda = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup \dfrac{n\log n}{-\log|c_n|}$$.
But I don't know how to move furthur.

Comment: If $\alpha =0$ then $\lambda =\infty$.

Comment: can you please explain how this is going to help?

Comment: If $f$ is of finite order then $\lambda $ is finite by definition. So you have a contradiction.

Comment: how do we guarantee that $\alpha$ is not negative?

Comment: The order  $\lambda$ is also a positive number. So $-\ln |c_n| >0$ for $n$ sufficiently large.